# C recursive function calling concept

Tags: c, function, recursion

```
/*Program to print all the numbers between a lower bound and a upper bound values*/     

#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void recur(int a, int b);
int main(void)
{
    int x,y;
    printf("Enter the lower and upper bound values: \n");
    scanf("%d %d",&x,&y);
    void recur(x,y);
    return 0;
}
void recur(int a,int b)
{
    if(a<b)
    {
        printf("%d /n",a);
        a++;
        void recur(a,b);
    }
}
```

The output I get is:

```
Enter the lower and upper bound values:
    10
    50
    process returned 0.
```

Is there anything wrong with the syntax or return type..? 
I've just started learning c.Need Help

Comment: `void recur(x,y);` --> `recur(x,y);` , `void recur(a,b);` ditto. also `/n` --> `\n`

Comment: You would also like to change "/n" to  "\n" to produce a newline, I believe.

Comment: Where is the process returned 0 message output in the program?  I don't see any printf message for it.   By the way, `void recur(x, y);` in main code only declares you have an external function that takes a undefined list of parameters and returns `void`, not calling it.  Somehow, you must be using some C11 compiler, or at least C98, as it's allowing you to declare a function prototype after executable code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both

```
void recur(x,y);
void recur(a,b);
```

*declares* the functions (prototype). To *call* them, change them to

```
recur(x,y);
recur(a,b);
```

Comment: Is it necessary to have different variables in the main() and recur()..? I mean formal parameters x,y and actual parameters a,b.

Comment: @Gow. Is it possible that a compiler might notice the unnecessary variables and optimise them away?

Comment: @Gow Yes. Why not try it out?

Answer (score 0):

```
void recur(int a,int b)
{
    if(a<b)
    {
        printf("%d /n",a);
        a++;
        //void recur(a,b); You need to call the function not to declare 
        // there is difference between dec and calling.
       recur(a,b); // is the correct way to do this .
    }
}
```

same requires in main() method though

Answer (score 0):

You have the following errors in your program:

1. When you call a function the syntax is

> ```
> funcName(param1, param2);
> ```

or, if function returns a value:

```
ret = funcName2(param3, param4, param5);
```

In your code, putting void at call time is a syntax error:

```
void recur(a,b);
```

This is how function is declared, not called. Attention there is a difference between function declaration and function definition.

2. If you want to print special chars in C, like newline, you need to print '\n' line this:

> ```
> printf("some message followed by newline \n");
> ```

Note that '\n' is a single char, even if you see a '\' and a 'n'. '\' has the purpose to escape the next char 'n' making it a new char. So '\n' is the newline character.

Other special characters in C are: '\t' for tab, '\' to actually print a '\'. Strings in C are enclosed in double quotes like "message" while chars are enclosed in single quotes like 'a', 'b', '\n', 'n', '\'.

Answer (score -1):

Here is your working code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void recur(int a, int b);
int main(void)
{
    int x,y;
    printf("Enter the lower and upper bound values: \n");
    scanf("%d %d",&x,&y);
    recur(x,y);           // change made here
    return 0;
}
void recur(int a,int b)
{
    if(a<b)
    {
        printf("%d \n",a);
        a++;
        recur(a,b);          // change made here
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you put any explanation/comment in your code... Are you only trying to demonstrate you are clever than him?  Why does it work? what was the mistake?  You are clever programming, but not explaining, I think.